# C# MVC Get Current View/Dynamic Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I am trying to return the current dynamic View to allow me to append a css class to an ActionLink if the current View is the same as the ActionLink.

As I am passing the majority of links through a specific route, in this case Pages, the `currentAction` will always be Pages in most cases, despite the actual View or Template being returned from the ActionResult called.

So for example if the url is http://mytestdomain.com/sport I would like the currentAction to be Sport and not Pages.

Please see my code below:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute("Pages", "{mainCategory}/{subCategory}/{pageName}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Pages", subCategory = UrlParameter.Optional, pageName = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

**HomeController**

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
{
    var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentView = htmlHelper.CurrentViewName();

    var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
    {
        InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName).ToHtmlString()
    };

    builder.AddCssClass("dropdown");

    var actionSplit = actionName.TrimStart('/').Split('/');

    actionName = actionSplit[0];

    if (controllerName == currentController && actionName == currentAction)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString().Replace("a href", "a class=\"active\" href").Replace("</li>", "").Replace("Home/", ""));
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString().Replace("</li>", "").Replace("Home/", ""));
}

public static string CurrentViewName(this HtmlHelper html)
{
        return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(((RazorView)html.ViewContext.View).ViewPath);
    }

public ActionResult Pages(string mainCategory, string subCategory, string pageName)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName))
    {
        subCategory = subCategory + "/" + pageName;
    }

    Page model;

    using (CMSEntities)
    {
        model = (from f in CMSEntities.GetPage(1, mainCategory, subCategory, "Live") select f).FirstOrDefault();
    }        

    return View(model.Template, model);
}
```

**Navigation.cshtml**

```
@Html.MenuLink(navigation.Title, "/" + Html.ToFriendlyUrl(navigation.Title), "Home")
```

I have tried using `var currentView = htmlHelper.CurrentViewName();` but this will always return Navigation as the ActionLink is being called from within a `[ChildActionOnly] public ActionResult Navigation()` for example `@{ Html.RenderAction("Navigation", "Home"); }` from within Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used 'HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath' to determine the current location to append the active class to the matching page link.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
{
    var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    var currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.TrimStart('/').Split('/');

    var mainCategory = currentUrl[0];

    var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
    {
        InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName).ToHtmlString()
    };

    builder.AddCssClass("dropdown");

    var actionSplit = actionName.TrimStart('/').Split('/');

    actionName = actionSplit[0];

    if (actionSplit.Length == 1)
    {
        if (controllerName == currentController && actionName == mainCategory)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString().Replace("a href", "a class=\"active\" href").Replace("</li>", "").Replace("Home/", ""));
        }
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString().Replace("</li>", "").Replace("Home/", ""));
}
```

I hope this proves useful to others :-)